# how to replace a value in an xml that contains a specific phrase

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my xml file

my.xml

```
.
.
.
<Package name="czst-stewart-aerodrome" active="true"/>
<Package name="kden-denver" active="true"/>
<Package name="lemd-adolfo-suarez" active="true"/>
<Package name="omdb-dubai-intl" active="true"/>
<Package name="yssy-sydney" active="true"/>
.
.
.
```

I want to replace “true” values with “false” for the lines that contain ‘kden’ ‘lemd’ ‘yssy’ and leave other lines intact

here is my code that does the job and replace ‘true’ values to ‘false’ but it does the job for the entire lines and not the above mentioned specific ones :

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\my.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $filename
$xml.SelectNodes('//*[self::title or self::subtitle]') |
    Where-Object { $_.'#text' -match 'true' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.'#text' = 'false' }
$xml.Save($filename)
```

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT based solution.

**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <Package name="czst-stewart-aerodrome" active="true"/>
    <Package name="kden-denver" active="true"/>
    <Package name="lemd-adolfo-suarez" active="true"/>
    <Package name="omdb-dubai-intl" active="true"/>
    <Package name="yssy-sydney" active="true"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@active[.='true'][starts-with(../@name,'kden')
        or starts-with(../@name,'lemd') 
        or starts-with(../@name,'yssy')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="active">false</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <Package name="czst-stewart-aerodrome" active="true" />
  <Package name="kden-denver" active="false" />
  <Package name="lemd-adolfo-suarez" active="false" />
  <Package name="omdb-dubai-intl" active="true" />
  <Package name="yssy-sydney" active="false" />
</root>
```

Comment: thanks, may I also use ‘includes’ or some other similar comment instead of ‘starts-with’ as some of the lines may include those kden, lemd, yssy phrases in the middle section of the line ?

Comment: Sure. You just need to use the `contains()` function instead of the `starts-with()`.

Comment: I'm now using notepad++ to transform my .xml file with this .xsl code and it works perfectly. Is there any way, however, to edit the .xsl code so that my output .xml is saved as my input .xml file ?

Comment: It is always 3 files: (1) Input XML, (2) XSLT, and (3) output file. By the way, the output file could be .csv, .txt, HTML, JSON, etc. not necessarily an XML file. 1+2=3

Comment: ok I just copy and paste new output file into the original, and i'm done. thanx a lot again for your time and kind sharing.